# What is Nanotechnology, basically?

Tags: nanoscience

Can someone elaborate [Nanotechnology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology)? Google has made me confused.

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad for this site. Did you try the Wikipedia page on the topic? Is there some specific aspect which has you confused?

Comment: Its implementations?

Answer (score 2):

> Nanotechnology is a part of science and technology about the control of matter on the atomic and molecular scale - this means things that are about 100 nanometres or smaller. Nanotechnology includes making products that use parts this small, such as electronic devices, catalysts, and sensors etc. Nanotechnology is defined as the study of structures between 1 nanometre and 100 nanometres in size. To give you an idea of how small that is, there are more nanometres in an inch than there are inches in 400 miles.

Taken from Simple English [Wikipedia](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotechnology).

Comment: :) Wikipedia. :D

Comment: @SyedSahl  Just a helpful hint in general: If a topic seems too confusing, selecting the "Simple English" language option on Wikipedia, tends to make things a lot simpler. :)

Comment: Well, thanks. I didn't have any idea about that option. It will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter - care to explain?

Comment: An answer should be something more that quoting the Wikipedia article, which could be linked in a comment.

Comment: @jinawee Why? If the excerpt answers the question entirely, I don't see a problem with it. I would argue its better than simply linking to the article, because there's no risk of the link breaking.

Comment: Guess so, retracted. A bad question doesn't make an answer bad.